# Is it possible to disable certain specific dates in Android datepicker ?

Tags: android, date, datepicker

I have a datepicker which disables past dates.

For my application, for example, certain events might happen only on every 'Fridays and Mondays' of every week. In that case the user must be able to select only Fridays and Mondays. The other dates must be disabled for selection. I do not want to validate after selection.

Please let me know if this is possible.

date picker code :

```
      final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
      int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
      int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    dpd = new DatePickerDialog(InfoActivity.this,
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                        int month, int dayOfMonth) {

                    month+=1;
                    String day = ""+dayOfMonth;
                    String mon = ""+ month;

                    try {
                        date=convertToINDateFormat(mon+"/"+day+"/"+year);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpd.setButton( DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Set", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which )
        {

           Intent i = new Intent(InfoActivity.this, ChooseSlot.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();

        }
    } );
```

.
.
.
.
.
.
.

```
             Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
             c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
             Date newDate = c.getTime();
             dpd.getDatePicker().setMinDate(newDate.getTime());
             dpd.show();
```

Comment: I'm asking for this question, have you got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can disable future dates using `dpd.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());`  But not specific future dates

Comment: Thanks but I do not want to disable all future dates. Only specific dates. Any Idea ?